# Azure DevOpsでPullRequestを発行しようとするとブランチに差がないためマージできない

Tags: windows, git, azure

### 概要

AzureDevOpsでPushした新しいブランチをmasterブランチにマージしようとPRを発行すると、以下のメッセージが表示されるだけでPR作成処理に進みません

> There are no changes to merge between the selected branches.

どのようにすればmasterブランチにマージできるようになるでしょうか?

### 詳細

リポジトリAのmasterブランチに、リポジトリB(リポジトリAからフォークしたもの)のdevelopブランチの変更をマージしようとしました
PRを作成しようとすると、上記のメッセージが表示されるだけで以降の処理を進められません
両ブランチでコードに差があることは確認済みです

やりたいこととしましては、developブランチをmasterブランチにマージすることです

Answer (score 0, accepted):

リポジトリBのmasterブランチに先にマージすることで、リポジトリAのmasterブランチにマージできました